# '..' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '...'

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I just trying to implement a hooks for fetching data from window by useState, I'm tripping up over generics and code as below

```
interface ApplyData {
 //...
}
interface ApplyRouterData {
 //...
}
export const useApplyRouterData = () => useWindowData<ApplyRouterData>();

export const useApplyData = () => useWindowData<ApplyData>();

export const useWindowData = <T extends ApplyData | ApplyRouterData>() => {
  return useState<T>(() => {
    return window.data;
  });
};
```

I also declare type for `window.data` like this

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    data: ApplyRouterData | ApplyData;
  }
}
```

but I got complier error om my hook

```
'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'IApplyResp | IApplyRouterResp'.
```

the type of `window.data` and generics are same as `IApplyResp | IApplyRouterResp` in my view, why? Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Imagine your function to get the window data was something like this: `const getWindowData = () => window.data;`. Your return type would be obviously the thing you expected. Introducing a generic here which extends from a certain type, would not restrict use to add different properties into. See here: https://tsplay.dev/Wy4Lbm does that help you a bit? tl;dr: Accessing a concrete type, and widen it up does not work as type errors would be the result. -> window.data needs to be a generic too.